# How do you decide the type of data to be returned in typescript based on the actual value of the schema?

Tags: typescript

I have a code setup like this.

I want the returned data to have a dynamic type constraint.

```js
type Schema = ('id' | 'name' | 'description' | 'content' | 'createdAt')[];

type Obj = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  content: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

function getBySchema(schema: Schema) {
  const result = /* Get the object of the specified field from somewhere according to the schema */
  return result;
}

const picked = getBySchema(["id", "name"]);

// Expect it to pass.
picked.name
// Expect it not to pass.
picked.createdAt
```

I specify Schema in the argument type of the function to get an input prompt.

[image: schema prompt]

How do I dynamically calculate the type of result based on the actual value of the schema?

I have tried the following, but it seems that it makes judgments based on all the types in the schema.

```js
type PickBySchema<T extends Record<string, unknown>, S extends Schema> = S extends (infer I)[] ? I extends string  ? {
  [K in I]: T[K]
} : never : never;
```

Comment: type Schema is dynamic, so you can't know in advance which values it will have in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(infer U)[] ? U : never` to infer the passed down tuple of strings and map them as result object keys as follows:

```
function getBySchema<T extends Schema>(schema: T): {
  [key in (T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never)]: Obj[key]} {
```

Explanation:

- `T extends Schema` makes sure that the passed in argument for `schema: T` is of type `Schema`.
- To use the passed in Schema entries as the returned object keys we will first need to create an interface using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where keys are derived from a union of the `Schema` strings that were **passed in**. For this we start the interface with the `key in` convention which is used to iterate through a union type to create property keys. The union type is created by extending the generic `T` variable and inferring its entries as a new union type by using the `(infer U)[] ? U : never` syntax which gets the smallest possible union type that is valid for T (a.k.a what was passed in). The `: never` expression is used to indicate that if a union cannot be inferred, the `key` will not be a valid value and cannot be used.
- Once we have derived the union of possible keys, we make the corresponding value type as `Obj[key]` which ensures that the property value has the correct type respective to the key.

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=62&pln=11&pc=97#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).

Further improvement to the codebase:

You don't necessarily have to manually type out the keys inside `Obj` type and assign them to the `Schema` type. You can automate this by using:

```
type Schema = (keyof Obj)[];
```

Playground [link][3].

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! With your help, I've basically achieved what I want, [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXlm7.png) but I'm having a problem with applying types to functions that don't work in some cases. Can you help me with this? Thanks a lot! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72416966/fails-when-using-custom-nested-schema-constraints-to-return-value-attributes)