# Fails when using custom nested schema constraints to return value attributes

Tags: typescript

I expect to implement a function that passes in a custom formatted schema that can constrain the value of the returned object's properties.

Full test code: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7A8lAvFAShAxogTgCYA8AzsPgJYB2A5gDRTlV1QA%20sCKA2gLoB8AbgBQoSFADKEADa5gEnAAsEAQwAq4aBgAUzGrXZRdFfYamyc8pao2QAlHwe8RozVDUqDGAN7CoUSkIALiYTOhF-ahV4CBC9cL8oQghSHCowYEpEajiw2gioNIgVYAhCAEFgXJZ84QBfFzFoAAVEcnQoX39A6v0CzOBZXoT-ACNEQhBh2v9gT1IQj1o%20EQbhYTxqdrnaRc8OroDgqAAiFQAzaQBrACtzk-pEqJiQk6bU9OAHxOSPygysjlEv4TrYIApPgFSFAVFAmoQmABXSD4UgQYBQRDnKAAKRUADcVBD-hjgIoSoVEPAwJRZNDgIgoGBpCoaLiCUS0iTvv4iiUypVXgAmAAMooAtCKAIySqVqEUioIKpUigB0CpFAC1vmsNtl2mA2lUoK12j5Ej1ThdrnceXDKINYqdTaSHbI7eNJq8XVBPSA7TsFlBuMDOqHusczpdbvdHv541Bnk63po-hk7QnflyAdkguH46DNMSMlCYXDNAjSMiIKj0ZjsXjCcXSeSMXhqbSUnDGczWdR2U3s184wnCvhiqUKsaTqKJdLZfLFcqFeqFdqR-46iPeI9dQB6Pdhg-xy3xWrH2Zup1nkQX30TKahGq3w%20zeZ7ZbOYTHtbHtBofhv0PbgAHJAhAxgQIGWQIKgEC-Vg0DA0QsDCFgkCk3QrNPkBdC%20UnSoQN4YjXHENREAUZR4HUTRiDUKAIAAD1KahCGhOAkGQfgOnKfB8BUEBiESQ5-G4ABpAJ%20yuCAQCxdxeBCCSmJYtin30fMAH53HE3gGOYiBWOhM9838LSxJMqBFh0vSVOhbQaHOGtYGQJwLK0mBUGUgzVI4lALNM4MxMYcjKJsWiPP4Xh-MsxMIHxGsLJCag4oS0cYuS%20L8AKOpuGk2TsTUKKhHWY8AHF0QAORSSdQuo4huBOQIHmDN55mahqmsYE4kxOYid1OQMTkAv8AKAlrOtOHqoqaKByuAKryDKWqVCE-wJBs7zoXMORlrBEclP0wy1LoYRuIwdavKO%20zqEc-AoAASVcgL7o2o7uAcpz7qlRgPru%206hSihMtK%2017VPMtLgaFUGtpkHbrGosE3IeoVEtizL8ySlL8FDTH0f8XGa0aNxmkoHArgAIRAZa6OhzhOMYABVWmQvhmjIDo-gzrDUSJLZJnLtU67bqgBmpSe%20MtNF2njIhkWpQxuXafem6nIZoVGG2yxds0QHR0lqGBaMvIkbV1GMtS0cCexhMrYU7SxN0w3jtoUMtLUHScftx3DsF36oBcvhXf92nfOQTSTVJimqdZ4hkEYOaFpqmOGcYMTOcDtKrc982svqFxzkRahLEBJlI4AMULnAaad0PGeZijWbBDn%20G0RJEFGG5FhHVIqJUEIGeEOwQhJsnKeptRGe4w4yXwRAAHdJsQDEQDrShqVkGJqEnE5VnWTZ2nHUgpQ6GkyYrovtENchGA6whmpOP1ersERD6lVVAhfdxlCgGJSFITxoBvCvEkRAXZqBLz0pQcgJwoBzxUEZREOAcApFIAXaQ0gQBJCgb2FehBhCv1VNBCAggoDHmQOZAhfoXD7wxIfKGGBT5XHPjgS%20Rob6NTvuwwa7CprEWfvglIQp36EE-gAUUYpASwMJ%20w1lnndX%20-9aAQAEaQIRRCSFkMQGAUgY1xGSIxCoGRfECA-xQQAlRaj5jcBFLwYRpDDzIC0TouhhCrE2NVEmIAA)

```js
function pickFunc<T extends DemoO, U extends ToSchemaType<T>>(
  obj: T,
  schema: U
): PickBySchema<T, U> {
  throw "not yet implemented";
}

const res = pickFunc(post, ["id", "body"]);
res.id;
// The message "title does not exist" was successfully displayed
res.title;
res.body;

// When using nested schema, the type constraint does not take effect
const res = pickFunc(post, ["id", ["tags", ["name"]]]);
res.id;
// Expect an error message
res.title;
// Expect an error message
res.tags[0].id
res.tags[0].name
```

I created the `PickBySchema` type to generate attribute field constraints for the object.

It is effective when used alone.

[PickBySchema example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXlm7.png)

```js
type PickBySchema<T extends DemoO, U extends ToSchemaType<T>> = {
  [K in U extends (infer U1)[]
    ? U1 extends string
      ? U1
      : U1 extends [infer U2, SelectSchemaType]
      ? U2 extends string
        ? U2
        : never
      : never
    : never]: T[K] extends string
    ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends (infer O)[]
    ? O extends DemoO
      ? PickBySchema<O, GetNestedSchema<U, K>>[]
      : never
    : never;
};

type PostOnlyId = PickBySchema<Post, ["id", ["tags", ["id", "name"]]]>;
```

At the moment is some confusion why when used in a function, it will not work when using nested schema?

Full test code: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7A8lAvFAShAxogTgCYA8AzsPgJYB2A5gDRTlV1QA%20sCKA2gLoB8AbgBQoSFADKEADa5gEnAAsEAQwAq4aBgAUzGrXZRdFfYamyc8pao2QAlHwe8RozVDUqDGAN7CoUSkIALiYTOhF-ahV4CBC9cL8oQghSHCowYEpEajiw2gioNIgVYAhCAEFgXJZ84QBfFzFoAAVEcnQoX39A6v0CzOBZXoT-ACNEQhBh2v9gT1IQj1o%20EQbhYTxqdrnaRc8OroDgqAAiFQAzaQBrACtzk-pEqJiQk6bU9OAHxOSPygysjlEv4TrYIApPgFSFAVFAmoQmABXSD4UgQYBQRDnKAAKRUADcVBD-hjgIoSoVEPAwJRZNDgIgoGBpCoaLiCUS0iTvv4iiUypVXgAmAAMooAtCKAIySqVqEUioIKpUigB0CpFAC1vmsNtl2mA2lUoK12j5Ej1ThdrnceXDKINYqdTaSHbI7eNJq8XVBPSA7TsFlBuMDOqHusczpdbvdHv541Bnk63po-hk7QnflyAdkguH46DNMSMlCYXDNAjSMiIKj0ZjsXjCcXSeSMXhqbSUnDGczWdR2U3s184wnCvhiqUKsaTqKJdLZfLFcqFeqFdqR-46iPeI9dQB6Pdhg-xy3xWrH2Zup1nkQX30TKahGq3w%20zeZ7ZbOYTHtbHtBofhv0PbgAHJAhAxgQIGWQIKgEC-Vg0DA0QsDCFgkCk3QrNPkBdC%20UnSoQN4YjXHENREAUZR4HUTRiDUKAIAAD1KahCGhOAkGQfgOnKfB8BUEBiESQ5-G4ABpAJ%20yuCAQCxdxeBCCSmJYtin30fMAH53HE3gGOYiBWOhM9838LSxJMqBFh0vSVOhbQaHOGtYGQJwLK0mBUGUgzVI4lALNM4MxMYcjKJsWiPP4Xh-MsxMIHxGsLJCag4oS0cYuS%20L8AKOpuGk2TsTUKKhHWY8AHF0QAORSSdQuo4huBOQIHmDN55mahqmsYE4kxOYid1OQMTkAv8AKAlrOtOHqoqaKByuAKryDKWqVCE-wJBs7zoXMORlrBEclP0wy1LoYRuIwdavKO%20zqEc-AoAASVcgL7o2o7uAcpz7qlRgPru%206hSihMtK%2017VPMtLgaFUGtpkHbrGosE3IeoVEtizL8ySlL8FDTH0f8XGa0aNxmkoHArgAIRAZa6OhzhOMYABVWmQvhmjIDo-gzrDUSJLZJnLtU67bqgBmpSe%20MtNF2njIhkWpQxuXafem6nIZoVGG2yxds0QHR0lqGBaMvIkbV1GMtS0cCexhMrYU7SxN0w3jtoUMtLUHScftx3DsF36oBcvhXf92nfOQTSTVJimqdZ4hkEYOaFpqmOGcYMTOcDtKrc982svqFxzkRahLEBJlI4AMULnAaad0PGeZijWbBDn%20G0RJEFGG5FhHVIqJUEIGeEOwQhJsnKeptRGe4w4yXwRAAHdJsQDEQDrShqVkGJqEnE5VnWTZ2nHUgpQ6GkyYrovtENchGA6whmpOP1ersERD6lVVAhfdxlCgGJSFITxoBvCvEkRAXZqBLz0pQcgJwoBzxUEZREOAcApFIAXaQ0gQBJCgb2FehBhCv1VNBCAggoDHmQOZAhfoXD7wxIfKGGBT5XHPjgS%20Rob6NTvuwwa7CprEWfvglIQp36EE-gAUUYpASwMJ%20w1lnndX%20-9aAQAEaQIRRCSFkMQGAUgY1xGSIxCoGRfECA-xQQAlRaj5jcBFLwYRpDDzIC0TouhhCrE2NVEmIAA)